# Angular $http with bbc radio api

Tags: json, angularjs, cors

I need to get this json from bbc radio:
http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/playlist.json

I can get it from POSTMAN, but then I try to get it from my angular app, I've got an error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/playlist.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Yes, I saw a lot simular guestions on Stack Overflow, but I think this is not a server task to solve.

In my angular code I've got this:

```
async: function (radio) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET', //or JSON
                    url: api.url + radio + '/playlist.json',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                    }
                })
                    .success(function (d) {
                        console.log('done');
                    })
                    .error(function (d) {
                        console.log('nope');
                    });
            }
```

And this in config:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

But CORS isn't working anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this playlist and BBC api doesn't support jsonp and have no CORS setup so the solution that I can think from top of my head would be to use i.e. CURL

http://plnkr.co/edit/66yErNbEkONrcC8LjqUV?p=preview

```
$http.jsonp('http://edeen.pl/curl.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function(response){
    $scope.playlist = response.data
    console.log(response.data)
  })
```

#### curl.php

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/playlist.json");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo $_GET['callback'].'('.$output.')';
```